# Unbale to run crypto-js in jmetter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, cryptojs

I'm trying to run crypto-js in PreProcessor JSR223 but i have an error (see below.
I don't found a solution to resolve it, can you check please?

```
javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: crypto-js.js:1424:48 Expected , but found =
            stringify: function (wordArray, urlSafe=true) {
                                                   ^ in <eval> at line number 1
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:470) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:454) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:406) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:978) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:561) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException: SyntaxError: crypto-js.js:1424:48 Expected , but found =
            stringify: function (wordArray, urlSafe=true) {
```

Load cryptoJs.js with success

Answer (score 1):

[Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) is a Java implementation which supports [ECMAScript 5.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/)

ECMAScript 5.1 was released in 2011 and now it's 2023 that's why it cannot support ECMAScript 6 or higher, that's why you're getting the error.

You could try looking for an archive version of crypto-js which is ECMAScript 5.1 compatible but I don't think it's something you should be doing because [Nashorn itself was removed in OpenJDK 15](https://openjdk.org/jeps/372)

So I would recommend re-implementing your cryptography logic in Groovy language, moreover it's t[he most performing scripting engine](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) and [it's recommended for using by JMeter authors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Comment: Thanks, I used groovy an that's works fine